# problem sorting using member function as comparator

Tags: c++, sorting, stl, compiler-errors

trying to compile the following code I get this compile error, what can I do?

---

> ISO C++ forbids taking the address of
>   an unqualified or parenthesized
>   non-static member function to form a
>   pointer to member function.

```
class MyClass {
   int * arr;
   // other member variables
   MyClass() { arr = new int[someSize]; }

   doCompare( const int & i1, const int & i2 ) { // use some member variables } 

   doSort() { std::sort(arr,arr+someSize, &doCompare); }

};
```

Comment: Exact duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/639100/627163; however, this here is posed in a much more succinct way.

Answer (score 32):

`doCompare` must be `static`. If `doCompare` needs data from `MyClass` you could turn `MyClass` into a comparison functor by changing:

```
doCompare( const int & i1, const int & i2 ) { // use some member variables }
```

into

```
bool operator () ( const int & i1, const int & i2 ) { // use some member variables }
```

and calling:

```
doSort() { std::sort(arr, arr+someSize, *this); }
```

Also, isn't `doSort` missing a return value?

I think it should be possible to use `std::mem_fun` and some sort of binding to turn the member function into a free function, but the exact syntax evades me at the moment.

**EDIT:** Doh, `std::sort` takes the function by value which may be a problem. To get around this wrap the function inside the class:

```
class MyClass {
    struct Less {
        Less(const MyClass& c) : myClass(c) {}
        bool operator () ( const int & i1, const int & i2 ) {// use 'myClass'} 
        MyClass& myClass;
    };
    doSort() { std::sort(arr, arr+someSize, Less(*this)); }
}
```

Comment: There is still a problem in this solution. STL sort called the distructor of the object that is passed to it as comparator, this would ruin my program !!!

Answer (score 15):

As Andreas Brinck says, doCompare must be static (+1). If you HAVE TO have a state in your comparator function (using the other members of the class) then you'd better use a functor instead of a function (and that will be faster):

```
class MyClass{

   // ...
   struct doCompare
   { 
       doCompare( const MyClass& info ) : m_info(info) { } // only if you really need the object state
       const MyClass& m_info;

       bool operator()( const int & i1, const int & i2  )
       { 
            // comparison code using m_info
       }
   };

    doSort() 
    { std::sort( arr, arr+someSize, doCompare(*this) ); }
};
```

Using a functor is always better, just longer to type (that can be unconvenient but oh well...)

I think you can also use std::bind with the member function but I'm not sure how and that wouldn't be easy to read anyway.

UPDATE 2014: Today we have access to c++11 compilers so you could use a lambda instead, the code would be shorter but have the exact same semantic.

Comment: Finally I found a sensible explanation for how to do this..! Thanks.

Comment: Very nice - and this can easily be adapted to a generic solution which takes a class ptr + method ptr.

Answer (score 12):

The solution proposed by Rob is now valid C++11 (no need for Boost):

```
void doSort()
{
  using namespace std::placeholders;
  std::sort(arr, arr+someSize, std::bind(&MyClass::doCompare, this, _1, _2));
}
```

Indeed, as mentioned by Klaim, lambdas are an option, a bit more verbose (you have to "repeat" that the arguments are ints):

```
void doSort()
{
  std::sort(arr, arr+someSize, [this](int l, int r) {return doCompare(l, r); });
}
```

C++14 supports `auto` here:

```
void doSort()
{
  std::sort(arr, arr+someSize, [this](auto l, auto r) {return doCompare(l, r); });
}
```

but still, you declared that arguments are passed by copy.

Then the question is "which one is the most efficient".  That question was treated by Travis Gockel: [Lambda vs Bind](http://www.gockelhut.com/cpp-pirate/lambda-vs-bind.html).  His benchmark program gives on my computer (OS X i7)

```
                        Clang 3.5    GCC 4.9
   lambda                    1001        7000
   bind                3716166405  2530142000
   bound lambda        2438421993  1700834000
   boost bind          2925777511  2529615000
   boost bound lambda  2420710412  1683458000
```

where `lambda` is a lambda used directly, and `lambda bound` is a lambda stored in a `std::function`.

So it appears that lambdas are a better option, which is not too much of a surprise since the compiler is provided with higher level information from which it can make profit.

Answer (score 5):

You can use [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html):

```
void doSort() {
  std::sort(arr,arr+someSize, boost::bind(&MyClass::doCompare, this, _1, _2));
}
```

Answer (score 2):

There is a way to do what you want, but you need to use a small adaptor. As the STL doesn't write it for you, can can write it yourself:

```
template <class Base, class T>
struct adaptor_t
{
  typedef bool (Base::*method_t)(const T& t1, const T& t2));
  adaptor_t(Base* b, method_t m)
    : base(b), method(m)
  {}
  adaptor_t(const adaptor_t& copy) : base(copy.base), method(copy.method) {}
  bool operator()(const T& t1, const T& t2) const {
    return (base->*method)(t1, t2);
  }
  Base *base;
  method_t method;
}
template <class Base, class T>
adaptor_t<Base,T> adapt_method(Base* b, typename adaptor_t<Base,T>::method_t m)
{  return adaptor_t<Base,T>(b,m); }
```

Then, you can use it:

```
doSort() { std::sort(arr,arr+someSize, adapt_method(this, &doCompare)); }
```

Answer (score 1):

The third argument in the calling of `std::sort()` is not compatible to the function pointer needed by `std::sort()`.  See [my answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58264279/opencv-drawing-a-box-around-an-object-from-an-image/58264579#58264579) for a detailed explanation for why a member function signature is different from a regular function signature.

Answer (score 1):

just make your helper function, static which you are going to pass inside the sort function.

for e.g

```
struct Item
{
int val;
int id;
};

//Compare function for our Item struct
static bool compare(Item a, Item b)
{
return b.val>a.val;
}
```

Now you can pass this inside your sort function

Answer (score 0):

A very simple way to effectively use a member function is to use operator<. That is, if you have a function called compare, you can call it from operator<. Here is a working example:

```
class Qaz
{
public:
Qaz(int aX): x(aX) { }

bool operator<(const Qaz& aOther) const
    {
    return compare(*this,aOther);
    }

static bool compare(const Qaz& aP,const Qaz& aQ)
    {
    return aP.x < aQ.x;
    }

int x;
};
```

Then you don't even need to give the function name to std::sort:

```
std::vector<Qaz> q;
q.emplace_back(8);
q.emplace_back(1);
q.emplace_back(4);
q.emplace_back(7);
q.emplace_back(6);
q.emplace_back(0);
q.emplace_back(3);
std::sort(q.begin(),q.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

Updating Graham Asher answer, as you don't need the compare but can use the less operator directly.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

class Qaz {
public:
    Qaz(int aX): x(aX) { }

    bool operator<(const Qaz& aOther) const {
       return x < aOther.x;
    }

int x;
};

int main() {
    std::vector<Qaz> q;
    q.emplace_back(8);
    q.emplace_back(1);
    q.emplace_back(4);
    q.emplace_back(7);
    q.emplace_back(6);
    q.emplace_back(0);
    q.emplace_back(3);
    std::sort(q.begin(),q.end());
    for (auto& num : q)
        std::cout << num.x << "\n";

    char c;
    std::cin >> c;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

can some one give an example where comparison function is to be used for set. for example

```
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

using namespace std;

struct MyStruct {
    unsigned p;
    unsigned t;
};


class MyClass {
public:
    void call() {
        ob["o1_10"] ={10, 1};
        mbp[ob["o1_10"].p].insert("o1_10");

        ob["o2_20_2"] ={20, 2};
        mbp[ob["o2_20"].p].insert("o2_20");

        ob["o3_30"] ={30, 3};
        mbp[ob["o3_30"].p].insert("o3_30");

        ob["o4_4_4"] ={4, 4};
        mbp[ob["o4_4"].p].insert("o4_4");

        ob["o5_10"] ={10, 4};
        mbp[ob["o5_10"].p].insert("o5_10");
    }
    
    
private:
    map<unsigned,set<string, compare>> mbp;
    // Question: how to define compare using struct, operator(), statice metthod or external method so that
    //           compare fetches ob[ol] and ob[0l2] and decide based on some rules
    //           so, comparions is not based on ol and o2 and it is based on some p and t in ob[o1] and ob[02]
    // static bool compare2(string& o1, string& o2) {
    //     // TODO: iS it possible to use this as customed comparison for set in mbp?
    //     // if (this->ob[ol].p > ob[o2].p)   return true;
    //     // if (ob[ol].p == ob[o2].p && ob[ol].t < ob[o2].t) return true;

    //     return false;

    // }
    
    map<string, MyStruct> ob;
};


int main() {
    MyClass my_class;
    my_class.call();

   
    
    return 0;
}
```