# Use class method comparator on std::sort

Tags: c++, oop, sorting, methods, std

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [problem sorting using member function as comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator)

Is it possible to use a class method as comparator function in std::sort?

for example:

```
std::sort(list.begin(),list.end(),object->comparator) //Doesn't compile
```

If yes, how I do this?

Comment: Is it an option to define an `operator<` for your class?

Comment: Already defined `operator ()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can use [`boost::bind`](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_47_0/libs/bind/bind.html):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
#include <boost/bind.hpp>

struct S {
  bool ascending;
  bool Compare(int lhs, int rhs) {
    return ascending ? (lhs < rhs) : (rhs < lhs);
  }
};

int main () {

  int i[] = { 1, 3, 5, 7, 8, 6, 4, 2 };
  S s;
  s.ascending = true;
  std::sort(i, i+8, boost::bind(&S::Compare, &s, _1, _2));
  std::copy(i, i+8, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";

  s.ascending = false;
  std::sort(i, i+8, boost::bind(&S::Compare, &s, _1, _2));
  std::copy(i, i+8, std::ostream_iterator<int>(std::cout, " "));
  std::cout << "\n";
}
```

Comment: This ought to be the accepted answer, as it ... answers the question

Comment: Do you need the `&` from `&S::Compare`?  I usually put it in there myself because I'm sure it's not wrong to do so, but I was just curious since I've seen examples of function pointers being passed without `&`.

Comment: @gred - [Empirically, yes](http://ideone.com/bEkBd). I don't have chapter&verse from the standard handy, but I suppose it is because `&S::Compare` is *not* a pointer-to-function. It is a pointer-to-member-function, an entirely different beast.

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide the function as a callback:

```
std::sort(list.begin(),list.end(),object::comparator)
```

Assuming your function is already `static`, I don't see any other problem.

Comment: Agree with static, but what about non-static methods?

Comment: @Vik check out the link posted as a possible duplicate.