# c++ unordered_set Comparator function for a user-defined class

Tags: c++, stl, comparator, unordered-set

I have something like this:

```
using namespace std;
class QuadraticPrimeSolution
{
    private:
        int a;
        int b;
        int numberOfPrimes;
        bool isPrime(int n, set<int> &primeHash);
    public:
        QuadraticPrimeSolution(int a, int b):a(a),b(b),numberOfPrimes(0){};
        void calculateNumberOfPrimes(set<int> &primeHash);

        int getNumberOfPrimes(){return numberOfPrimes;}
};




class QuadraticPrimeSolver
{
    private:
        struct classcomp {
          bool operator() (QuadraticPrimeSolution& lhs, QuadraticPrimeSolution& rhs)
          {
            return lhs.getNumberOfPrimes()>rhs.getNumberOfPrimes();
          }
        };
        set<QuadraticPrimeSolution, classcomp> solutions;
        set<int> primeHash;
        QuadraticPrimeSolution getMaxSolution();
        int a;
        int b;

    public:

        QuadraticPrimeSolver(int a, int b):a(a), b(b){};
        void solve();

};

bool QuadraticPrimeSolution::isPrime(int n, set<int> &primeHash)
{
    if(primeHash.empty())
    {
        primeHash.insert(n);
        return true;
    }
    for(auto it= primeHash.begin(); it!= primeHash.end(); it++)
    {
        if(n%(*it)==0)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
    primeHash.insert(n);
    return true;
}


void QuadraticPrimeSolver::solve()
{
    for(int i=(-1)*a; i<=a; i++)
    {
        for(int j=(-1)*b; j<=b; j++)
        {
            QuadraticPrimeSolution aSolution = new aSolution(i,j);
            aSolution.calculateNumberOfPrimes(primeHash);
            solutions.insert(aSolution);
        }
    }

}
int main()
{
    QuadraticPrimeSolver QPS(0,40);
    QPS.solve();
}
```

Basically what I am trying to do is compute and store each QuadraticPrimeSolution into a hash table in QuadraticPrimeSolver which I can then access later.

My question is, is my comparator implementation correct? Right now compiler is complaining about my comparator, and the following line for inserting into a set.

```
solutions.insert(aSolution);
```

Please help!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem sorting using member function as comparator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator)

Comment: `unordered_set` is unordered. You might want `std::set`.

Answer (score -1):

```
class building
{
public:
    int getPosition() const {return position;};
private:
    int height;
    int position;
};

class ManyBuildings
{
public:
    void populateBuildings(std::vector<std::string> buildings);
private:
    class comparePosition {
    public:
        bool operator () (const building &lhs, const building &rhs) {
            return lhs.getPosition() > rhs.getPosition();
        }
    };
    std::set<building, comparePosition> buildings;

};
```

- use `set` instead of `unordered_set`
- template parameter for `set` should be a type, not a function

Comment: That comparator needs more `const`.