# Sort vector based on value outside of class

Tags: c++, sorting

I have a `std::vector<myStruct>`, a simple version of my struct would look like this:

```
struct myStruct {
    glm::vec3 Position;
};
```

The above struct is declared in a class:

```
class myClass {
    private:
        struct myStruct {
            glm::vec3 Position;
        };

    std::vector<myStruct> structVector;
    glm::vec3 outsidePosition;

};
```

But the issue I'm having is how do I sort my `structVector` based on the distance between `structVector.Position` and `outsidePosition`.

I've tried using `std::sort` like this:

```
std::sort(this->structVector.begin(), this->structVector.end(), this->sortFunction);
```

where `sortFunction` is declared as:

```
GLboolean myClass::sortFunction(myStruct const &x, myStruct const& y)
{
    GLfloat dist1 = glm::length(this->outsidePosition - x.Position);
    GLfloat dist2 = glm::length(this->outsidePosition - y.Position);
    return dist1 < dist2;
}
```

but I get a compilation error stating that there's no overloaded method for `std::sort`. Where am I going wrong here?

Errors:

`Error  C2672   'std::sort': no matching overloaded function found`

`Error  C3867   'myClass::sortFunction': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member`

Comment: are you using the header #include<algorithm>?

Comment: @HariomSingh yes, I am

Comment: Please post the entire error. It appears you're trying to use a class method as your compare function.  You should read this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator

Comment: can we see implementation of glm ?

Comment: What's `TransparentTransformImpl`, and how, if at all, is it related to `myClass`?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [problem sorting using member function as comparator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator)

Comment: I pasted in the wrong class name, I updated it @RetiredNinja

Comment: `std::sort(structVector.begin(), structVector.end(), [this](myStruct const &x, myStruct const& y) { return sortFunction(x, y); });`

Comment: @IgorTandetnik If you post your comment as an answer explaining the syntax (specifically the `[this]` part I will mark it correct

Comment: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/lambda

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`std::sort` takes a predicate to compare element.
As your method requires extra information, you have to bind it in some way;
lambda (via capture) is a simple one:

```
std::sort(structVector.begin(),
          structVector.end(),
          [this](myStruct const &lhs, myStruct const& rhs)
          {
              return this->sortFunction(lhs, rhs);
          });
```

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you use a map instead of a vector, with the key being the calculated distance, so the sorting would be done automatically at insertion of the values?

Answer (score -3):

I think your problem is that this three-argument form of `std::sort` expects the third argument to be a class, which `this->sortFunction` is not.  It might be more straightforward to replace `sortFunction` with a definition of the `<` operator in `myClass` - then you can simply call `std::sort(this->structVector.begin(), this->structVector.end())`

Comment: sort works fine with a function, just not a member function.  http://ideone.com/cnAcIv

Comment: `std::sort` expects a callable as its third argument. An instance of a class overloading `operator()` is one form of a callable; there are others.