# storing member function pointers of different classes in a single map

Tags: c++, qt, callback, pointer-to-member

I've built a router that is similar in syntax to laravel's router to route QWebsocket messages

member function pointers must be void and have a `Message` reference parameter and I'm storing the callbacks and the instances in a struct called `MemberCallbackInfo`

```
class CNTRLR{}; // a dummy class

using MemberCallback = void (CNTRLR::*)(Message &);

struct MemberCallbackInfo
{
    CNTRLR *instance;
    MemberCallback ptr;
};
```

and then I'm using template functions so that I can pass any class with any function as long as the function signiture matches the parameter

```
template <class T> 
static void get ( const QString& action,
                  T *instance,
                  void (T::*ptr)(Message &) )
```

to actually store the instance and the callback, I have to perform `reinterpret_cast` like this

```
    MemberCallbackInfo obj={
    reinterpret_cast<CNTRLR *>(instance),
    reinterpret_cast<MemberCallback>(ptr)
};
callBacks->insert(action, obj); //callbacks is QMap<QString,MemberCallbackInfo>
```

now if I want to register a callback, I just have to do this

```
Route::post("user/auth", ControllerInstance, &AuthController::authenticate);
```

**this Implementation worked fine on gcc and I even tweaked it to work on MSVC 2017 so it works really well.
but I'm still wondering...is there a better way to Implement such Router, at least without the need to use `reinterpret_cast` .
I'm using this class on a Qt project so I think it's possible to utilize their Metaobject system to Implement a better solution but I don't know how.**

here is the full implementation:
router.h

```
#ifndef ROUTER_H
#define ROUTER_H

#include <QObject>
#include "message.h"


#ifdef Q_CC_MSVC
#pragma pointers_to_members(full_generality,virtual_inheritance)
#endif

class CNTRLR{}; //MSVC will throw C2440 when using reinterpret_cast with undefined classes

using MemberCallback = void (CNTRLR::*)(Message &);

struct MemberCallbackInfo
{
    CNTRLR *instance;
    MemberCallback ptr;
};

typedef QMap<QString,MemberCallbackInfo> MemberCallbacks;

class Router : public QObject
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit Router(QObject *parent = nullptr);
    void route(Message &message);

    template <class T> static void registerRoute(MemberCallbacks *callBacks,
                                          const QString& action,
                                                 T *instance,
                                                 void (T::*ptr)(Message &))
    {
        MemberCallbackInfo obj={reinterpret_cast<CNTRLR *>(instance),
                                reinterpret_cast<MemberCallback>(ptr)};
        callBacks->insert(action, obj);
    }
    template <class T> static void get   (const QString& action, T *instance, void (T::*ptr)(Message &))
    {
        registerRoute(&getRoutes,action,instance,ptr);
    }
    template <class T> static void post  (const QString& action, T *instance, void (T::*ptr)(Message &))
    {
        registerRoute(&postRoutes,action,instance,ptr);
    }


private:
    static MemberCallbacks getRoutes;
    static MemberCallbacks postRoutes;
};

typedef Router Route;

#endif // ROUTER_H
```

router.cpp

```
    #include "router.h"

MemberCallbacks Router::getRoutes;
MemberCallbacks Router::postRoutes;

Router::Router(QObject *parent) : QObject(parent)
{

}

void Router::route(Message &message)
{
    if(message.method()=="GET")
    {
        MemberCallbackInfo cb= getRoutes.value(message.action());
        (cb.instance->*cb.ptr)(message);
    }
    else if(message.method()=="POST")
    {
        MemberCallbackInfo cb= postRoutes.value(message.action());
        (cb.instance->*cb.ptr)(message);
    }
}
```

Comment: *member function pointers must be void and have a Message reference parameter* -- With C++11, lambdas, `std::function`, and `std::bind`, I don't see a need for restricting the last template parameter to certain instances of a class.  It could be "universal", as long as the function takes a `Message` reference and returns `void`.  Also, maybe if you see how functions such as [std::sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator) accomplishes similar issues.

Comment: You should have a look onto [`std::function`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function). This allows to store method pointers to any object (together with instance pointer), as well as pointers to free standing functions and lambdas. (The latter are fine to "bind" additional arguments.) And: It allows a clean (i.e. standard conform) implementation of what you intend to achieve (as far as I understood your question).

Comment: @Scheff
I know about std::function, but I need to store a list of std::function in a QMap
QMap<QString,std::function> and this is not possible because std::function needs template arguments and I can't store more than one type of std::function in a QMap

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie
I'm putting this restriction because the Router is only intended for routing messages and should not be used for other purposes in this project, for anything else, I have Qt's signals and slots to accomplish other types of callbacks.
I'll look into std::sort, thanks for the help

Comment: Of course, `std::function` needs template arguments. You have to use your signature which you want to call with: `std::function<void(Message &)>`. With this, you can store it in any std or Qt container.

Comment: @Scheff
I'll try it out then, thanks for the help

Comment: Btw. Qt signals are similar because they are built for the very similar purpose, i.e. calling callbacks in an arbitrary set of receivers which registered for this.