# comparer in a map c++

Tags: c++, compare

I have this method in a class:

```
//Compare function, Needed to construct the Map
bool StudentRegister::operator() (const CustomString &lhs, const CustomString &rhs) const{
   return lhs < rhs;
}
```

and this in another method tried to make a map:

```
 bool(*fn_pt)(const CustomString &, const CustomString &) = &this->operator ();            
 map<CustomString, float, bool(*)(const CustomString &, const CustomString &)> tmpMap(fn_pt);
```

I get the following:

```
StudentRegister.cpp:168:89: error: cannot convert 'bool (StudentRegister::*)(const CustomString&, const CustomString&)' to 'bool (*)(const CustomString&, const CustomString&)' in initialization
```

Any suggetsion?

Comment: read the error carefully and compare the types of the arguments. Also member functions are different from free functions

Comment: The problem is with the pointer to function, not the arguments

Comment: the function pointer has the wrong type and type of the arguments is part of that

Comment: does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1902311/problem-sorting-using-member-function-as-comparator ( + you need to fix the argument types)

Comment: Since you're using `<` to compare the strings why do you need the custom compare at all? That's what it would use by default.